# Why is casting a struct to AnyObject not a compile error in swift?

Tags: swift, casting

The code below compiles and works in swift.

```swift
struct TestStruct {
    let value: String = "asdf"
}

func iWantAReferenceType(object: AnyObject) {
    print(String(describing: object))
}

let o: TestStruct = TestStruct()

iWantAReferenceType(object: o as AnyObject)
```

I expected this to be a compile error because a struct can never conform to AnyObject.  As demonstrated below by code that fails to compile.

```swift
protocol Test: AnyObject {

}

//Compile error: because a struct cannot be AnyObject
struct TestStruct: Test {
    let value: String = "asdf"
}
```

I am aware there is some bridging that can happen for certain types such as String.  This would convert the value type of a reference type.

```swift
print(Mirror(reflecting: "asdf").subjectType) //print: String
print(Mirror(reflecting: "asdf" as AnyObject).subjectType) //print: NSTaggedPointerString
```

In writing this question I thought to see what the type of the cast object was and it seems it is also bridged in someway.

```swift
print(Mirror(reflecting: o).subjectType) //prints: TestStruct
print(Mirror(reflecting: o as AnyObject).subjectType) //prints: _SwiftValue
```

Why is this type of casting allowed?  It seems to be breaking the contract for the function that is expecting a reference type.

I stumbled on this by accident when refactoring some code to support value types, to my surprise it had already been working for value types even though I thought it wouldn't.  Is it safe to rely on this behaviour?

Comment: For even more fun, try `print(type(of: object), ObjectIdentifier(object))` and `dump(object)`

Comment: Also, this is worth a read: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39

Comment: Thanks @Alexander the blog seems to indicate this capability is solely to support ObjC interoperability and should not be used for anything else.

"Since Swift does not interoperate with Objective-C on Linux, there is no support for bridging conversions such as string as NSString or value as AnyObject. Swift code that intends to be portable across Cocoa and the Swift Core Libraries should use the value types exclusively."

I reconsider my current usage as it is probably an abuse which is not intended.

Comment: Yep. Stuff like this is important for when you want to pass your Swift values (Structs, Enums) to be used in Objective C, such as for storing Swift values in NSArray and other Objective C containers (which can only store values by reference, hence the existence of classes like `NSValue`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature to facilitate passing to Cocoa. Any struct can be wrapped into a `SwiftValue` reference type. If you print `type(of: object)` you'll see the wrapper.

I don't think there is any contract for "expecting a reference type." More importantly, while "value types" and "reference types" exist in Swift, what really matter is value and reference *semantics*, which are not expressible in the language. You can create value semantics in reference types and reference semantics in value types, so the Swift type system really isn't of any help in that regard.

The important point here is that you only get this unusual behavior if you explicitly request it by asking for `as AnyObject`. There are very few reason to write that, and if you are, you had better know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Rob!

My original code had a redundant cast `as AnyObject` for a protocol that conformed to `AnyObject`.  I was surprised to find that when I removed the constraint from the protocol that the rest of the code still worked as expected, as you explained the cast is no longer redundant but actually causing value types to be wrapped in a `SwiftValue`.

Can you elaborate at all about when it is acceptable to use this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like you've gotten you answer in the comments above. I completely agree with your assessment. You should basically never use it, unless it's required for ObjC interop.