# Testing type for class conformance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, anyobject

*EDIT: The previous answers alluded to in the comments don't answer the question, which was how to determine if any given Type was a reference type and how to safely conform said type to AnyObject.*

Testing against the passed type doesn't work, as the underlying type could be optional, or it could be a protocol, in which case one needs to know the passed *instance* is a class type or value type.

The solution I came up with is similar to the revised answer provided below.

---

So I have a new dependency injection framework, [Factory](https://github.com/hmlongco/Factory).

Factory allows for scoped instances, basically allowing you to cache services once they're created. And one of those scopes is *shared*. Any instance shared will be cached and returned just as long as someone in the outside world maintains a strong reference to it. After the last reference releases the object the cache releases the object and a new instance will be created on the next resolution.

This is implemented, obviously, as simply maintaining a weak reference to the created object. If the weak reference is nil it's time to create a new object.

And therein lies the problem

Weak references can only apply to reference types.

Factory uses generics internally to manage type information. But I can create Factories of any type: Classes, structs, strings, whatever.)

Scopes use dictionaries of boxed types internally. If an instance exists in the cache and in the box it's returned. So what I'd *like* to do is create this...

```swift
private struct WeakBox<T:AnyObject>: AnyBox {
    weak var boxed: T
}
```

The AnyObject conformance is need in order to allow weak. You get a compiler error otherwise. Now I want to box and cache an object in my shared scope with something like this...

```swift
func cache<T>(id: Int, instance: T) {
    cache[id] = WeakBox(boxed: instance)
}
```

But *this* also gives a compiler error. (Generic struct WeakBox requires T to be a class type.)

So how to bridge from on to the other? Doing the following doesn't work. Swift shows a warning that "Conditional cast from 'T' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds" and then converts the type anyway.

```swift
func cache<T>(id: Int, instance: T) {
    if let instance = instance as? AnyObject {
        cache[id] = WeakBox(boxed: instance)
    }
}
```

I'd be happy with the following, but again, same problem. You can't test for class conformance and you can't conditionally cast to AnyObject. Again, it always succeeds.

```swift
private struct WeakBox: AnyBox {
    weak var boxed: AnyObject?
}
func cache<T>(id: Int, instance: T) {
    if let instance = instance as? AnyObject {
        cache[id] = WeakBox(boxed: instance)
    }
}
```

What I'm doing at the moment is something like...

```swift
private struct WeakBox: AnyBox {
    weak var boxed: AnyObject?
}
func cache<T>(id: Int, instance: T) {
    cache[id] = WeakBox(boxed: instance as AnyObject)
}
```

Which works, but that `instance as AnyObject` cast depends on some very weird Swift to Objective-C bridging behavior.

Not being able to test for class conformance at runtime is driving me bonkers, and seems like a semi-major loophole in the language.

You can't test for conformance, and you can't cast for conformance.

So what can you do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `func cache<T:AnyObject>(id: Int, instance: T) ` ?

Comment: And yes, *anything* can be cast to AnyObject in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54384581/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39033194/1187415.

Comment: See also this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184911/1187415, where various (runtime) checks are suggested.

Comment: Doing `func cache<T:AnyObject>(id: Int, instance: T)` just kicks the can down the road. At some point I need to go from a T of any type to T:AnyObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin notes in a comment, any value can be cast to `AnyObject` in Swift, because Swift will wrap value types in an opaque `_SwiftValue` class, and the cast will always succeed. There is a way around this, though.

The way to check whether a value is a reference type without this implicit casting is to check whether its *type* `is AnyObject.Type`, like so:

```swift
func printIsObject(_ value: Any) {
    if type(of: value) is AnyObject.Type {
        print("Object")
    } else {
        print("Other")
    }
}

class Foo {}
struct Bar {}
enum Quux { case q }

printIsObject(Foo()) // => Object
printIsObject(Bar()) // => Other
printIsObject(Quux.q) // => Other
```

Note that it's crucial that you check whether the type `is AnyObject.Type` *not* `is AnyObject`. `T.self`, the object representing the type of the value, is itself an object, so `is AnyObject` will always succeed. Instead, `is AnyObject.Type` asks "does this inherit from the *metatype* of all objects", i.e., "does this object which represents a type inherit from an object that represents all object types?"

---

**Edit:** Evidently, I'd forgotten that Swift includes `AnyClass` as a synonym for `AnyObject.Type`, so the check can be simplified to be `is AnyClass`. However, leaving the above as a marginally-expanded explanation for how this works.

---

If you want this method to also be able to handle `Optional` values, you're going to have to do a bit of special-casing to add support. Specifically, because `Optional<T>` is an `enum` regardless of the type of `T`, you're going to need to reach in to figure out what `T` is.

There are a few ways to do this, but because `Optional` is a generic type, and it's not possible to ask "is this value an `Optional<T>`?" without knowing what `T` is up-front, one of the easier and more robust ways to do this is to introduce a protocol which `Optional` adopts that erases the type of the underlying value while still giving you access to it:

```swift
protocol OptionalProto {
    var wrappedValue: Any? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalProto {
    var wrappedValue: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .none: return nil
        case let .some(value):
             // Recursively reach in to grab nested optionals as needed.
             if let innerOptional = value as? OptionalProto {
                 return innerOptional.wrappedValue
             } else {
                 return value
             }
        }
    }
}
```

We can then use this protocol to our advantage in `cache`:

```swift
func cache(id: Int, instance: Any) {
    if let opt = instance as? OptionalProto {
        if let wrappedValue = opt.wrappedValue {
            cache(id: id, instance: wrappedValue)
        }
        
        return
    }
    
    // In production:
    // cache[id] = WeakBox(boxed: instance as AnyObject)

    if type(of: instance) is AnyClass {
        print("\(type(of: instance)) is AnyClass")
    } else {
        print("\(type(of: instance)) is something else")
    }
}
```

This approach handles all of the previous cases, but also infinitely-deeply-nested `Optional`s, and protocol types inside of `Optional`s:

```swift
class Foo {}
struct Bar {}
enum Quux { case q }

cache(id: 1, instance: Foo()) // => Foo is AnyClass
cache(id: 2, instance: Bar()) // => Bar is something else
cache(id: 3, instance: Quux.q) // => Quux is something else

let f: Optional<Foo> = Foo()
cache(id: 4, instance: f) // => Foo is AnyClass

protocol SomeProto {}
extension Foo: SomeProto {}

let p: Optional<SomeProto> = Foo()
cache(id: 5, instance: p) // => Foo is AnyClass
```

Comment: I wonder if the question can be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184911/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Testing AnyObject conformance is different from casting from Any.

Comment: @MartinR To be honest, I'd completely forgotten about `AnyClass` as a synonym for `AnyObject.Type`. I think it's reasonable to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. The actual type T could be an optional protocol type, and this test doesn't let me know if the underlying type conforming to the protocol is a class type.

Comment: @MichaelLong Yeah, if you need to unwrap `Optional` values dynamically this way, then you'll need to special-case them. I've updated the answer to reflect this with a more robust implementation.

Comment: This is basically what I'd come up yesterday. Might have had the solution sooner had everyone not rushed to assume the question was a duplicate and that the same exact answer applied. But you did point me towards a solution so thanks.

Comment: @MichaelLong I think the results would have been different had we known the constraints on handling optional values and similar up-front — which, to be fair, you may not have been thinking of at the time (or may not have considered relevant). "How can I tell if a value is an object" is a duplicate, and a very different question from "How can I tell if a value is an object, or if it's an optional which contains an object?", which is not. Regardless, I'm glad you got to a helpful answer!

Comment: @MartinR Given the updated constraints on the problem, I think it's worth considering de-duplicating this question.

Comment: Doesn't work if value is referenced as a protocol.

Comment: @IsaacPaul The above checks _should_ work even if the value is given as a protocol — do you have an example snippet which shows what you're seeing? For instance, [this SwiftFiddle](https://links.itaiferber.net/C7REG) shows the code behaving as expected when given a value of an existential protocol type.

Comment: @ItaiFerber It seems the difference is that I'm using generics `func cache<T>(id: Int, instance: T)`

Comment: Yea looks like I have to cast to Any for it to work.

Comment: @IsaacPaul Ah, yeah. With a generic method, the concrete type of the parameter `instance` becomes `P` (the protocol type itself), and when the parameter to `type(of:)` is of a concrete type, it returns that type statically. When given an existential type instead, `type(of:)` "looks through" the existential to return what the actual value is (which is why the cast to `Any` works). [For slightly more detail, if you're curious: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051520/why-does-typeof-return-metatype-rather-than-t-type/67051785#67051785]

Answer (score 0):

So this took a while to figure out and even longer to track down the clues needed for a solution, so I'm providing my own code and answer to the problem

Given the following protocol...

```swift
private protocol OptionalProtocol {
    var hasWrappedValue: Bool { get }
    var wrappedValue: Any? { get }
}

extension Optional : OptionalProtocol {
    var hasWrappedValue: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return false
        case .some:
            return true
        }
    }
    var wrappedValue: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return nil
        case .some(let value):
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

And a box type to hold a weak reference...

```swift
private protocol AnyBox {
    var instance: Any { get }
}

private struct WeakBox: AnyBox {
    weak var boxed: AnyObject?
    var instance: Any {
        boxed as Any
    }
}
```

Then the code to test and box a give type looks like...

```swift
func box<T>(_ instance: T) -> AnyBox? {
    if let optional = instance as? OptionalProtocol {
        if let unwrapped = optional.wrappedValue, type(of: unwrapped) is AnyObject.Type {
            return WeakBox(boxed: unwrapped as AnyObject)
        }
    } else if type(of: instance) is AnyObject.Type {
        return WeakBox(boxed: instance as AnyObject)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note that the type passed in could be a class, or a struct or some other value, or it could be a protocol. And it could be an optional version of any of those things.

As such, if it's optional we need to unwrap it and test the actual wrapped type to see if it's a class. If it is, then it's safe to perform our AnyObject cast.

If the passed value isn't optional, then we still need to check to see if it's a class.

There's also a `StrongBox` type used for non-shared type caching.

```swift
struct StrongBox<T>: AnyBox {
    let boxed: T
    var instance: Any {
        boxed as Any
    }
}
```

And the final cache routine looks like this.

```swift
func resolve<T>(id: UUID, factory: () -> T) -> T {
    defer { lock.unlock() }
    lock.lock()
    if let box = cache[id], let instance = box.instance as? T {
        if let optional = instance as? OptionalProtocol {
            if optional.hasWrappedValue {
                return instance
            }
        } else {
            return instance
        }
    }
    let instance: T = factory()
    if let box = box(instance) {
        cache[id] = box
    }
    return instance
}
```

Source for the entire project is in the [Factory repository](https://github.com/hmlongco/Factory).